# DateTime manipulation inside Linq to entities query

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

running this code:

```
public bool CheckTime(DateTime date, int UserID, int TotalTimeMin)
        {
            using (var context = new myDB())
            {         
                var assginments = from c in context.Assignments.Where(x=>(x.AssignmentDateTime < date && x.AssignmentDateTime.Value.AddMinutes(TotalTimeMin) > date) || 
                    (x.AssignmentDateTime < date.AddMinutes(TotalTimeMin))) select c;

                if(assginments != null) return false;
                else return true;
            }


        }
```

I get this error.

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMinutes(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

TotalTimeMin is int. I am not sure what cause this:
AssignmentDateTime is DateTime? and maybe this is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that LINQ-to-Entities doesn't know how to translate DateTime.AddMinutes into your datastore language (probably SQL). Maybe that will point you in the right direction. I'll need more time to actually figure out a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually played with it a little and you probably right, no matter what I do, can't use AddMinnute inside the query (although I can easily write it with SQL....)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `EntityFunctions.AddMinutes` (requires EF 4):

```
    public bool CheckTime(DateTime date, int UserID, int TotalTimeMin)
    {
        using (var context = new myDB())
        {         
            var assginments = context.Assignments
                                     .Where(x=>(x.AssignmentDateTime < date 
                                                && EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(x.AssignmentDateTime,TotalTimeMin) > date) 
                                                || (x.AssignmentDateTime < date.AddMinutes(TotalTimeMin)));

            if(assginments != null) return false;
            else return true;
        }
    }
```

Note that `assignments` will *never* be null (but it might be empty -- test `assignments.Any()`).

Comment: Thanks. (I've omitted the ToList and check for count... but the EntityFunctions is new for me and that what I was looking for.

Comment: Apparently Entityfunctions is obsolete. One can use DbFunctions.AddMinutes() now (EF 6.x).